# which is appropriate preposition and why?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Vijay distributed the sweets ________ his friends.

**A)** Among

**B)** TO

Which one is Correct? Book says **among**, but I want to know why **To** cant be used. I think grammatically both correct. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this a matter of correct or incorrect. It might be one of those "which is the best answer" situations.

> [among](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to)
>    :  in shares to each of <*The candy was divided among the friends.*>

*To* has so many definitions and is such a versatile pronoun that I think we could argue that *to* also works here. It just happens that *among* has the exact meaning we seek.

Comment: I think "among" implies that every single person will least have a sweet. However, to me, ''to'' sounds like you were not very meticulous in the distribution. Perhaps, I am wrong. Am I right?

Comment: i found your answer more appropriate.

Comment: @Cardinal Ok, by "we seek" I meant that I am assuming that the sentence wants you to believe that Vijay was meticulous and gave everyone candy. That is why I believe _among_ is "better" than "to" But I agree, _to_ sounds like you were lazy and handed one of you friends the candy (which means that one way or another, the group got candy). So we agree that _to_ also works.